# Test-Path PowerShell Issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search several servers to see if a specific Registry key exists.

It looks like the code below is working, but as I start to add the final part of the key, it stops "finding" stuff.  I can start to add `a*`, then `ab*` as the last key, but as soon as I get to the third character or even the full string that I know is there, it comes back False saying it did not find it.

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\input.txt | `
   Select-Object @{l='ComputerName';e={$_}},@{l='KeyExist';e={Test-Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\services\*abcdefg*" }}
$servers | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: You are not check remote registries. Just you own computer every time. The double *'s are redundant.

Comment: Are you perhaps intending to test the registry path on *different* computers? Your current command just checks the registry on your local computer, for each server name you pipe in from the file

Comment: For remote registry , you should do something like this: `$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",
           $_.machinename);
  $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname);
  $value = $key.GetValue('AutoAdminLogon')`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you run `Test-Path` against the local computer for each remote server name. Unfortunately `Test-Path` doesn't support querying remote registries.

You could use WMI:

```
$RegProv = [wmiclass]"\\$servername\root\default:StdRegProv"
if($RegProv.EnumKey(2147483650,"System\CurrentControlSet\services").sNames -like 'abc*'){
    # key starting with abc exists
}
```

Wrap it in your calculated property like this:

```
@{Name='KeyExists';Expression={[bool](([wmiclass]"\\$_\root\default:StdRegProv").EnumKey(2147483650,"System\CurrentControlSet\services").sNames -like 'abc*')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the remote registry like this :

So for each server it will get the registry value and it will store the value in the arraylist and will display the final result.

Presently in your code, you are basically checking locally only.

```
   #####Get Registry Value #### 
$main = "LocalMachine"
$path= "registry key path"
$servers = Get-Content c:\input.txt #-- Get all the servers
$arr=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($Server in $servers)  
{ 

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($main, $Server) 
$regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey($path) 
$Value = $regkey.GetValue($key) 
$arr.Add($Value)
}
$arr
```

Note: Change the placeholders accordingly

Comment: With this approach you lose the correlation between value and machine name

Comment: Then what should be the best way . Could you please let me know. I do not want to use get-itemproperty or get-itempropertyvalue

Comment: Instead of using an ArrayList, you should output an object with both properties (using the `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator, or `New-Object psobject`), then assign the entire `foreach(){}` loop to a variable

Comment: Yes, that would be much more better.